# Return Query when Using HTTR in a function in R

Tags: r, function, web-scraping, httr

I was learning about the package httr and webscraping based on an exercise from Dataquest and attempting to implement it in my own practice programs. My issue comes from trying to make a query within a function.
For example, the following code:

```
api_request <- function(base_url, loc){
  url <- modify_url(paste(base_url), 
                    path = paste(loc))
  response <- GET(url)
  return(response)
}
```

When I run the code, everything initially appears to run correctly. The status comes back with the code 200 and no errors or warnings show up. However, I cannot get the response to save to the global environment. I've tried this method as well as changing the `return(response)` to just `response` in the function as recommended by Dataquest, but it will not save to the global environment.

I can get this to work outside of a function, but I want to implement it inside of a function so that if any errors occur when making this query I can stop the function and not save a 404 link.

How can I get the query to return from the function so that I can reference it later on in the code?

Comment: You need to explicitly store the output when you call the function: `res <- api_request(base_url, loc)`

Comment: How are you calling the `api_request()` function? Are you assigning the function return value to variable?  `answer <- api_request("x", "y")`

Comment: Thank you both so much, I was forgetting to assign the function to a variable. That's got it working now, thanks again!